# C++ main architecture

Tags: c++, object-oriented

I'm working on a file interpreter and this is the code I have in my main() function right now:

```
// main.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//
#include <iostream>
#include <crtdbg.h>

#include "FileReader.h"
#include "Interpreter.h"


int main()
{
    
    {
        std::unique_ptr<FileReader> fileReader = std::make_unique<FileReader>("https://www.swiftcoder.nl/cpp1/start.txt");
        //fileReader->getData();

    }
    
    {
        std::unique_ptr<Interpreter> interpreter = std::make_unique<Interpreter>();
        //interpreter->decode();

    }

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();


    return 0;
}
```

Can this be considered 'good' or 'clean' code? What improvements or changes should I make?

Comment: Does a vote on my post mean it's 'good' code?

Comment: No, a vote on your question just means someone thinks the question is a good question.

Comment: How does this work since you don't call fileReader->getData or interpreter->decode and you also don't tell the interpreter what to interpret?

Comment: My question isn't really about functionality. I just wonder if this would be a 'clean' way of calling functions from other classes inside main(). And if this is undoubtedly free of memory leaks?

Comment: "I want to call functions from other classes" is the wrong way to think about classes.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: I don't really think there's enough here to review. Without seeing `FileReader` and `Interpreter` we can only guess how they "should" be called.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments have noted, this is such a tiny amount of code that it's somewhat difficult to comment on it.

So, take the following with a grain of salt. It may be reading entirely too much intent into entirely too little code to really mean much.

#### Pointers

You're using `unique_ptr`s, which are generally preferred over raw pointers, *but* the code shows no indication that you have any real need or use for pointers of any kind, at all. Ultimately, you're just instantiating a couple of objects.

I'd consider use of pointers in C++ a decision that requires at least a little justification. It's not necessarily terribly difficult to justify, but it should be avoided unless you honestly have *some* reason to do it.

In this case, I see no hint of any such reason. So, lacking any reason to think it's a good idea, my immediate reaction is that it's probably not.

If I were writing the code, my immediate take would be to just create `filereader` and `interpreter` as automatic variables.

#### Comments

You only have one comment.

```
// main.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to me to add anything useful to the code. Anybody who knows C or C++ even a little bit can see that this contains `main`, and knows what `main` means/is/does.

#### Return value from main

C++ automatically includes code to indicate a successful return from `main` if execution reaches the end of the function without executing another `return` first. As such, your `return 0;` is simply redundant.

#### Portability

I'd generally prefer to write most code to be as generic and portable as possible. As such, if I were doing this, I'd write at least a thin wrapper around `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks`, and put that bit of code in a separate file, so it would be relatively easy to (for one example) have the build files link in one version for Windows, and another for Linux, so you can keep the bulk of the code portable, and keep that bit of non-portable code segregated from the rest (segregation may be bad in real life, but in programming, it's often useful).

Comment: You might want to remove your answer, this question is in the Close Queue, and it should be closed.

Comment: It should NOT be deleted. Any help is help and it makes no sense to delete this. Thanks a lot @Jerry Coffin for your clear answer! Helped me perfectly.

Comment: Can I ask you how you would write a thin wrapper around `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks`? I'm not familiar with wrappers. @Jerry Coffin

Comment: @TristanvO: I'd change `main` to include a call to something like `show_leaks()`, then have a Windows-specific file containing `void show_leaks() { _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); }` Then when/if you want to do similar on, say, Linux, add a new file specific to Linux that also implements `show_leaks()`, but using some Linux-specific code (e.g., `malloc_info`). Then you can (for example) have your build tool select the right file based on the target OS.